# view what command a function is running is postgres

Tags: postgresql

Say I run a function: `select somefunction()` and I wanna know what statement it is performing at the moment

`select * from t` does not help because it shows the 'select somefunction()' line and not the exact statement.

Is there a way to see what's up?

Thanks,
h

Comment: `SELECT * FROM t` ? Eh? Do you mean `select * from pg_stat_activity` ?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the [PL/PgSQL debugger](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/edb-debugger/) - which should be preinstalled in most PostgreSQL installs and is used via PgAdmin-III after activating it in `postgresql.conf`.

Alternately, consider adding `RAISE NOTICE` statements in your code at significant points you wish to know about.

There is no facility that I know of to get a "stack trace" of an active SQL statement including the (possibly nested) function calls. It'd be quite nice, but AFAIK nobody's implemented such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you.

> CREATE FUNCTION somefunction() returns table(query text) as $$ select
>   current_query::text from pg_stat_activity where current_query not like
>   '% somefunction();' $$ language sql;